# Helping new user with posting an excellent self-answered question

Tags: discussion, new-users

Richard has [posted](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9806/how-does-earth-conductivity-affect-thetakeoff-angle-of-a-vertical-monopole) a really nice article, but sadly in the question field alone.

I tried to guide him through the process of answering his own question, but that didn't work out – he deleted the question, all my praise for its content nonwithstanding.

Can we

- revive that question
- split the answer-content from the question into an answer
- make it so that Richard at least can get part of the reputation this answer (and question) deserves and
- let Richard know he was absolutely welcome to post this, and that the conversion to Q&A format is really just a formality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we
>
> - revive that question

Technically, yes, but it would be a bad precedent to undelete content that the author chose to delete and was permitted to, especially as doing so could not fully solve the problem as per the below.

> - split the answer-content from the question into an answer
> - make it so that Richard at least can get part of the reputation this answer (and question) deserve and

It is not possible, even for moderators, to create an answer attributed to someone else. The most that can be done is to create an answer which *nobody* gets rep for ('community wiki' answer); this can be used in cases such as an answer written in comments, where, again, if the user does not post their own answer it is not possible to truly do it for them.

> - let Richard know he was absolutely welcome to post this, and that the conversion to Q&A format is really just a formality?

I think you've already done the best you can.

Comment: Agreed. I think Richard is a little frustrated. Hopefully, he'll  follow your advice, Marcus

Comment: My first attempt at posting this info appeared as expected in my web browser:  the title (only), then the text and graphic below it.

If I delete what is posted below the question sentence I would only replace it with what is already there.

What is the point?

Comment: @RichardFry There is a separate place for the _answer_ to the question, which appears once you click the box labeled "Answer your own question" (or button labeled "Answer your question" if the question is already posted). You should put the text there instead, so that it is considered an answer instead of a question.

Comment: Maybe the problem is due to my selecting the box marked Q&A in my post.  Was that a mistake?  If so, how can it be fixed?  Thanks,

Comment: @RichardFry What is the point? Several: consistent formatting, and so that the system understands that what you have posted is not an _unanswered question_, and so that it is on equal grounds with answers other people might post.

Comment: @RichardFry To fix it, undelete your post and press the "Answer Your Question" button and put the text in there. Or just put _some_ text in and we can fix it up for you if you have any trouble.

Comment: I deleted the original answer, but the site wouldn't accept that.  Finally I got a workaround, but maybe someone can repair that so that the post meets your standards.

Comment: Also would appreciate someone removing all the comments that followed that original post.  Thanks.

Comment: @RichardFry Thanks! Generally one should use that space to expand on what exactly the question is. A place to start is repeating the question that was in the title but with more words, or an example of a dubious claim you've heard, or such.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented above.  Now I'm thinking to post another self-answered question, but can't get past the first page to do that (see graphic linked below).  It isn't offering me any way to enter the text and graphic that I wish to post.  Advise, pls?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IjoK.gif

Comment: @RichardFry From the other elements missing in your picture I am guessing you might have JavaScript disabled in your browser or something else interfering. In that case, if you don't want to try to fix that, just post the question and then click the answer button on the page afterward — the result is the same. (There still must be text for the question, either way.)

Comment: Actually, it can't be an all-JavaScript problem because I see the tag input working, but the editor controls are also missing. If things _were_ normal there would be a second box below the question box, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN4y6.png Maybe you just need to scroll down?

Comment: There was nothing useful  below that to scroll to.  But I just re-started the New Question process on a new tab of my browser, and that appears to do what is needed.  Thanks (again).